# Loading FB logo from FB's own CDN

Tags: facebook, image, cdn, css-sprites

Is there a url we can src for the FB logo that will be the same src as what gets generated after FB.init completes?

I doubt that I can hard-code the FB CDN link below and expect it to work for all users and also stay up-to-date.

https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yL/r/FGFbc80dUKj.png

I basically want to reduce another image request for a FB logo sprite that already gets loaded with any other social plugin I have on my site.

[image: FB sprite]

Comment: Considering the link is now dead, i guess it wasn't such a safe idea in the end -_-

Answer (score 1):

Try using font-awesome's icons.
[fa-facebook-official: Font Awesome Icons](http://fontawesome.io/icon/facebook-official/)

and apply facebook logo's official color in css ( #3B5999 ).

Answer (score -3):

Given that the URL still (after 5 months) resolves to the image correctly, I would say that you are probably OK using the link you have.

As a fall-back, though, you may want to consider hitting the link with an ajax call and changing your usage of that URL to a locally cached copy just incase the link ever goes dead. It's *slightly* more work, but it's a functional way to use a 3rd party's image and still fall back to your own version if theirs goes away.